# using quantifiers for predicates, prenex normal form

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, computability, quantifiers

Say we have $A=B$

iff $\forall x (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$) and $\forall y (y \in B \Rightarrow y \in A$)

can we write the above as:
$\forall x [(x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$) and $(x \in B \Rightarrow x \in A$)]
if so, why? I don't really understand equivalent formulations of these statements.

Comment: Yes; and because $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $(P \Rightarrow Q) \land (Q \Rightarrow P)$ we have $A=B$ iff $∀x \ (x ∈ A \Leftrightarrow x ∈ B)$.

Comment: You must consider that $\forall x Px$ and $\forall y Py$ means the same thing: "every "object" is $P$".

Comment: FYI set theoretic equality usually has $\forall x.A \in x \iff B \in x$ as part of the definition also.

Answer (score 2):

See rules for [prenex operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Conjunction_and_disjunction).

But for the question above, we have to use the rules for ["distributing" quantifiers](https://www.cse.buffalo.edu//~rapaport/191/distqfroverandor.html) :

> $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(x))$ is equivalent to $(∀xP(x) ∧ ∀xQ(x))$.

Thus, $∀x(x∈A \Rightarrow x∈B) \land ∀y(y∈B \Rightarrow y∈A)$ is equivalent to :

> $∀x \ [(x∈A \Rightarrow x∈B) \land (x∈B \Rightarrow x∈A)]$,

and this, in turn, is equivalent to :

> $∀x(x∈A \Leftrightarrow x∈B)$.

Comment: so if I had $\exists x \forall y R(x,y)$ and $\exists x' \forall y' S(x',y')$ then we cannot change it to $\exists x \forall y (R(x,y) and S(x,y))?$ what can we change it to?

Comment: is it equivalent to: $\exists x \exists x' \forall y (R(x,y)$ and $S(x',y)$)?

Comment: @user352102 - $\exists$ distribute over $\lor$ (or) nut **not** over and: "there is number that is even and there is a number that is odd" but **not** "there is a number that is even and odd".

Comment: also, what if I had $\exists x R(x)$ and $\forall y S(y)$ is this equivalent to $\exists x \forall y$ (R(x) and S(y)) as well as $\forall y \exists x$ (R(x) and S(y))??